# sql sum - dealing with dirty duplicates in join table

Tags: mysql

I am pulling reports out of a bookkeeping system. The system has a nasty habit of putting duplicates in the DB which it handles internally (instead of making it clean in the first place!)

as an example - this is the totals table for invoice 125:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+
| invoice_id | code      | amount   |
+------------+-----------+----------+
|        125 | sub_total | 300.0000 |
|        125 | tax       |  30.0000 |
|        125 | total     | 330.0000 |
|        125 | sub_total | 300.0000 |
|        125 | tax       |  30.0000 |
|        125 | total     | 330.0000 |
+------------+-----------+----------+
```

and the invoice table for the same id

```
+-----+----------+
| id  | amount   |
+-----+----------+
| 125 | 330.0000 |
+-----+----------+
```

I would like to generate a total sales and taxes for a period (for Australian BAS)

my MWE query (that works if the data is clean) is

```
select sum(a.amount) as total_sales, sum(c.amount) as total_GST
from 7cn_invoices a 
    INNER JOIN 7cn_invoice_totals c ON a.id = c.invoice_id
where c.code = 'tax';
```

However, since there are duplicates in the total table I get total sales double what they should have been. What is the best way to solve this (other than patching the code)?

Comment: Is this the entire `totals` table? No other columns?

Comment: oop.. yup there is a deleted_at column and its filled for the duplicate... but this question is probably worth answering for other people who don't have that solution..

Comment: No, not really. This is not a real-world situation. The `deleted_at` timestamp column makes sense; a real-world bookkeeping system with duplicate entries does not.

Comment: I've had systems generate duplicates before without any other flags.. they simply did a distinct query to bring it back in.. never underestimate how pear-shaped old systems can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove duplicates By using a subquery with `DISTINCT`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE 7cn_invoice_totals  (
>   `invoice_id` INTEGER,
>   `code` VARCHAR(9),
>   `amount` DECIMAL(10,4)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO 7cn_invoice_totals 
>   (`invoice_id`, `code`, `amount`)
> VALUES
>   ('125', 'sub_total', '300.0000'),
>   ('125', 'tax', '30.0000'),
>   ('125', 'total', '330.0000'),
>   ('125', 'sub_total', '300.0000'),
>   ('125', 'tax', '30.0000'),
>   ('125', 'total', '330.0000');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE 7cn_invoices  (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `amount` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO 7cn_invoices 
>   (`id`, `amount`)
> VALUES
>   ('125', '330.0000');
> ```

> ```
> select sum(a.amount) as total_sales, sum(c.amount) as total_GST
> from  7cn_invoices a 
>     INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `invoice_id`, `code`, `amount`  FROM 7cn_invoice_totals) c ON a.id = c.invoice_id
> where c.code = 'tax';
> ```
>
> ```
> total_sales | total_GST
> ----------: | --------:
>         330 |   30.0000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1e5dfa702fdc60cbd309cfc43c8be20c)*

Comment: There are no duplicates, the OP failed to mention a `deleted_at` nullable column that's `null` for valid entries.

Comment: thanks nbk this solves the problem nicely